# is it possible to use macOS 10.13 sdk to build chrome in macOS 13.2 with M1 chip

Tags: macos, chromium, apple-m1

I am change the macOS sdk to 10.13 when build the chromium in macOS 13.2 with M1 chip, what I have tried to change configure `chromium/src/build/config/Mac/mac_sdk.gni` file and set sdk:

```
# Path to a specific version of the Mac SDK, not including a slash at the end.
  # If empty, the path to the lowest version greater than or equal to
  # `mac_sdk_min` is used.
  mac_sdk_path = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk"
```

but this config show error:

```
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.cc:5:
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.h:9:
In file included from ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/cstdint:146:
In file included from ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/stdint.h:124:
In file included from ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/clang/17/include/stdint.h:52:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:53:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.cc:5:
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.h:9:
In file included from ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/cstdint:146:
In file included from ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/stdint.h:124:
In file included from ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/clang/17/include/stdint.h:52:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:53:
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:32:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'
typedef __darwin_intptr_t       intptr_t;
        ^
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.cc:5:
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.h:11:
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator_constants.h:16:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/vm_page_size.h:33:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/mach_types.h:80:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/host_info.h:66:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/message.h:75:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/port.h:91:
In file included from ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/boolean.h:73:
../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/mach/machine/boolean.h:35:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

this is the build command:

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

what should I do to build the chromium success? is it possible to build with `macOS sdk 10.13 + M1 chip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible for x86_64.

The first version of macOS to support arm64 hardware was macOS 11.0, so if you want to compile *for M1 targets*, you'll have to use the 11.0 SDK or newer.

But if you just want to build *on M1 hosts*, then you can use the 10.13 SDK to cross-compile Chrome for x86_64. According to [this help page](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/main/docs/cross_compiles.md), the way to do that should simply be:

```
gn gen out/Default --args='target_cpu="x64"'
```